# Powershell script, write-output

Tags: powershell, output, prompt

I need to write a PowerShell script to do the following,
"Lab assignment: Write a PowerShell script that prompts the user to enter their first and last name then prints back out a greeting with their name in it (e.g. Hello, John Anderson). Proper script formatting will be 50% of your grade. "

brand new to PowersSell and scripting. help is very appreciated.

I have tried using the write-output cmd

```
Write-Output "Hello " (Read-Host -Prompt 'What is your name?')
```

I get the prompt to enter name but the output is on 2 different lines

I need them on the same line and to print.

Comment: SO isn't a script writing service, but I can give you some pointers.  I would recommend breaking your script into multiple lines.  Maybe store the user input into a variable and then output that variable in your `Write-Output` line

Comment: Read `Get-Help Write-Output` and then omit it completely, concatenating the two strings with a `+` => `"Hello "+(Read-Host -Prompt 'What is your name?')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt (`Read-Host -Prompt ...`) is the *2nd* argument passed to `Write-Output`; instead, you want it inside the *1st* (and only) argument, the `"Hello "` string.

This will work:

`Write-Output "Hello $(Read-Host -Prompt 'What is your name?')"`